# Retrieve NT login username on Visual Force page - For non-logged users

Tags: visualforce, authentication, user-management

I'm looking for an opportunity to retrieve the NT login username from a Visualforce page or from an Apex class.
It would be HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name in C#.

--Extension--
Our business requirement contains a **non-authenticated salesforce page** which captures some business related data. Additionally we have to identify the user who sends this form. 
Because of the users all have the nt login username, we would have to capture that and store in a custom object if it's possible without a big effort.

Comment: Do you use Single Sign On (SSO) to log in to Salesforce or are the SF credentials separate from domain credentials?

Comment: I extended the post to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not necessarily the user's NT login name. `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` refers to the name of the account a web process is running under and is normally set as a service account in IIS, though ASP.Net web apps can be set to impersonate the logged in user (generally this is reserved for intranet applications.) The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has more detailed information. This variable only exists in ASP.Net applications.

If you need the logged in user's name you can use `$User` [global variable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global.htm) that exposes that information.

**Update**

Based on the edit to your question, I think the only way to do this is to either host the page/application on an IIS server and have that application send the data to Salesforce or to use single sign-on against your Active Directory server; otherwise there is no way to expose that information to Salesforce.

Comment: But that user name won't be the NT login name.

Comment: That's true, but unless @tamastom's org is using SSO with an AD server I don't see how that information can be obtained.

Comment: I agree. It's just a clarification. Of course, if they were using Silverlight they could (probably) get at that information, although I don't know how that would help them.

Comment: Well we don't even speak about logged in users. I have an unauthenticated salesforce page where I'd like to capture the windows login username at least.